# Библиотека перетаскивания элементов c вложенностью?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Интересует готовое решение по перетаскиванию элементов(div блоков) с возможностью вкладывать их друг в друга. А на выходе чтобы выдавалась структура для хранения в базе например.

Чтобы её использовать для создания редактора.

Comment: это вы так дерево описали?

Comment: в принципе любая библиотека с методами имеющими в названии `drag` или `draggable`